# How to add checkbox to existing administration page

Tags: 7, forms

For a custom module i would love to add a checkbox to "BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION" under "admin/config/development/performance". I know how to add a new admin page but this is just one checkbox and i think it would fit more there.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: you use the form_alter hook. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Comment: Thanks i've figured it out. Used `hook_form_alter` and `$form['bandwidth_optimization']['my_module']`

Answer (score 3):

To alter a form implemented by another module, you just implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). You probably need to change the #weight property of the form element you are adding, to avoid it is rendered in the wrong place.

```
function mymodule_form_system_performance_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
 // Add the checkbox to $form.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add another item on the performance settings form you must implement the [hook_for_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).

To get the form id you just need to inspect the form an get the id attribute of the form tag:

[image]

In your custom module you will have the form alter function like this:

```
function mymodule_form_system_performance_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $form['bandwidth_opt'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION'),
    );

   return $form;
}
```

Notice that the hyphens of the element id in the HTML are replaced by underscores in the function declaration.

Another good tip is the [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) page.

Comment: thanks, just got it with `hook_form_alter` as suggested in the first commet within my question. I still wonder if `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` would be "the better way" to do it since you're the second one suggesting it.

Comment: got it working like you did it in your example but the array should be called `$form['bandwidth_optimization']['my_module']` instead. Otherwise you would override the existing one.

Comment: In fact both are right but I use to implement the hook_for_alter() when I have more than one form to alter on my custom module so I use a switch for the $form_id. In the other hand using the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter seems to be more clear and easier to maintain the code.
Here goes somethig from the Drupal API page.
"Modules can implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to modify a specific form, rather than implementing hook_form_alter() and checking the form ID, or using long switch statements to alter multiple forms."